# Is there an alternate way to display NPAPI in chrome since chrome removed the NPAPI support?

Tags: java, google-chrome, applet

I was using chrome to display my applet content. But now the support is removed from chrome. Please suggest if there is an alternate way to display applet content in chrome browser. Minimal change is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The Oracle website (https://java.com/en/download/faq/chrome.xml) recommends that you either change your code to be a Java Webstart application, or get your users to change to Safari or Internet Explorer.

> Please suggest if there is an alternate way to display applet content in chrome browser.

AFAIK, there isn't one.

Comment: An applet might be launched using JWS either embedded or free floating (outside the browser).  While the removal of the NPAPI kills the first, it has no affect on the second.